# gradient background in cross

Tags: android, gradient

[image]

How can I make this gradient background?

My code is as per below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<corners android:radius="@dimen/_10sdp"/>
<gradient
    android:type="linear"
    android:angle="135"
    android:startColor="#D3D3D3"
    android:endColor="#FF0000" />

<size android:height="@dimen/_40sdp"
    android:width="@dimen/_100sdp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: As i tested, its giving perfect output as you asked for, I dont see any problem.

Comment: @AmrishKakadiya  how you used it to set as background can you please share

Answer (score 0):

**drawable/gradlient_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    <gradient
        android:angle="135"
        android:endColor="#FF0000"
        android:startColor="#D3D3D3"
        android:type="linear" />

    <size
        android:width="100dp"
        android:height="40dp" />
</shape>
```

Example to set background in TextView

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="OK"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="16dp" />
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: check my uploaded image in that gradient is horizontally crossed not vertical only or not only horizontally but it's in slant and I want the same as that image only.

Comment: add   android:centerColor="#FF0000" in gradient block it will resolve.

Comment: still not getting result as desired.